# Automatically update an image on an ASP.Net WebForm on a schedule

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, webforms, scheduled-tasks

So I am using c# and asp.net webforms to make an image change by itself each week.
Eventually this is going to be a facebook application (iframe).

What is the best approach to do the above? I have done some research but couldn't find anything that really helps.

Comment: Which part of this task are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I honestly cannot figure out how to begin with this as I have never done anything similar before.

Comment: Are you going to be adding a new image each week, or do you have a collection of images that you want to randomly choose from, based on the week?

Comment: Is your issue with scheduling? Creating images? Overwriting existing images? Something else.

Comment: I have a set of images already. One is displayed at the moment, However, I would like to make it change not randomly but by order automatically on a weekly basis.

Comment: Is your website only live for a certain period of time? If not you are going to run out of images eventually. Maybe if you updated your question indicating the logic behind what images are used for each week we could be more hepful

Comment: It will be available for a month only.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easiest to simply change the image weekly manually.

Comment: Yeah I know, but my customer wants it to perform this task automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are showing the image via an `Image` control on an ASP.Net webform? If so, this is simple enough.

The image you show inside the `Image` control is determined by the ImageURL property of the control. This needs to be a string of text containing the URL of an image file (either in `gif`, `jpg`, `jpeg`, `bmp`, `wmf` or `png` format).

In the C# code associated with the WebForm, you can use the below method to change the image programmatically based on the day of the month (`myImage` is the name of the Image control on your WebForm):

```
private void SetImage(int day)
{
    if (day >= 1 && day <= 7)
    {
        myImage.ImageUrl = @"~\ImageOne.jpeg";
    }
    else if (day >= 8 && day <= 14)
    {
        myImage.ImageUrl = @"~\ImageTwo.jpeg";
    }
    else if (day >= 15 && day <= 21)
    {
        myImage.ImageUrl = @"~\ImageThree.jpeg";
    }
    else if (day >= 22 && day <= 31)
    {
        myImage.ImageUrl = @"~\ImageFour.jpeg";
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Day");
    }
}
```

Obviously change the dates as appropriate and add another block to the if statement if needs be, and update the URL's for the various images also. You can call this method like so:

```
SetImage(DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Comment: Okay but when and how will setimage be called?

Comment: In your Page_Load event should work, you can find this by double clicking on the whitespace inside web form, Visual Web Developer will take you straight there